# I want list only list the text using grep or any other option using shell script

Tags: text-processing, deduplication

I have folder called `rules/resources`, in that I have the sub folders lets say `A`, `B` and `C`. Each sub-folder contains `constraint.yaml`.

Now I want to `grep` the `constraint.yaml` files which contain the string `assetType`. I tried to use `grep` as follows:

```
grep -rIih assetType rules/resources/
```

and I get this output:

```
assetType: cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/CloudFunction
assetType: cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/CloudFunction
assetType: cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/CloudFunction
assetType: cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/CloudFunction
assetType: cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/CloudFunction
assetType: bigquery.googleapis.com/Dataset
assetType: artifactregistry.googleapis.com/Repository
assetType: composer.googleapis.com/Environment
assetType: composer.googleapis.com/Environment
assetType: composer.googleapis.com/Environment
assetType: apigateway.googleapis.com/Gateway
assetType: apigateway.googleapis.com/Gateway
```

But I don't want to display the `assetType` string, also it should remove the repeated values. The desired output would look like this:

```
cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/CloudFunction
bigquery.googleapis.com/Dataset
artifactregistry.googleapis.com/Repository
composer.googleapis.com/Environment
apigateway.googleapis.com/Gateway
```

Comment: find the solution for it .

grep -rIih assetType ./rules/resources/ | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -u

Answer (score 0):

If your `grep` (which seems to be GNU `grep`, as it uses `-r`, `-I`, `-h` all of which are non-standard GNU extensions) was built with PCRE support, you could do:

```
grep -rIihPo 'assetType:\s*\K.*' rules/resources/
```

Where we use `-o` to `o`utput the text matched by the regexp, `-P` switches to perl-like regexs, `\K` says what's to `K`eep in the match.

Pipe to `sort -u` to sort and remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, sitting on rules/resources:

```
fgrep -Rh assetType `find ./ -name constraint.yaml.`|uniq
```

on *fgrep* the **-R** switch will ensure that your search is recursive, **-h** will suppress the prefixing of file names on output, the *find* part between apices will take care of feeding *fgrep* with the files content, and finally  *uniq* will remove repetitions. Moreover this should work regardless the depth of the directory tree.